# Who is writing to my file or why lsof did not display the writer but reader do

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor, lsof

I did the following actions on two separate terminals:

**1s term:**

Start process that is writing to file in background:

```
└──> while true; do date >> log; sleep 1; done &
[1] 20604
```

Get the PID of last process that is running in background:

```
└──> echo $!
20604
```

**2nd term:**

Display the content of file being written:

```
└──> tail -f log
Thu May  7 18:48:20 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:21 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:22 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:23 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:24 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:25 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:26 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:48:27 CEST 2015
```

**1st term:**

Check who is accessing the file (note that there is only reader)

```
└──> lsof log
COMMAND   PID  USER      FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
tail    21038  wakatana   3r   REG    8,1     5340 797966 log
```

After Following `kill` the `tail -f` on 2nd terminal terminated and `lsof` returned empty output:

```
└──> kill 21038
└──> lsof log
└──>
```

**2nd term:**

Then I started `tail -f` again and I saw that data was still written to log file. This means that some process is still writing to log file:

```
└──> tail -f log
Thu May  7 18:52:33 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:34 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:35 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:36 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:37 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:38 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:39 CEST 2015
Thu May  7 18:52:40 CEST 2015
```

In this case I actually know the mysterious PID of process which is writing to file, it is PID 20604 so I can kill it and log file will stop growing.

My questions are:

1. Why did not `lsof` display (even if is issued repeatedly) the process that is actually writing to
   log file? I understand that 20604 belongs to `bash` and it is not bash that is writing to file directly but it's child `date`. But the `lsof` did not display neither `bash` nor `date`.
2. What if I did not know the PID 20604? How can I track the writing process then?

PS: The shell used: GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic engineering problem in the form of **asynchronous sampling** here.

Essentially, every long period of waiting time, a process will be very quickly spun up, write to a file, and then die.

Entirely asynchronous to that, you run `lsof` which looks for open files - but only effectively at one instant in time that *probably will not match when the file is being written*.   (In actuality, `lsof` performs a multi-step operation, but there's probably only one-shot opportunity to catch *any given* writer).

It might be tempting to think that if you ran `lsof` enough times in a loop, you would eventually catch the writer in the act - and perhaps you will.  However, depending on how your system's scheduler and I/O functionality works, it is possible that the writing process might be so brief as that there is never any chance for another process to run during it.

If you want a version of this which you can catch in the act, continue to have the generation spaced in time within a parenthesized subshell, but make the writing one consistent operation:

```
(while true; do date ; sleep 1; done) > log &
```

Or, if you want to try to catch brief events, you might look at the `inotify` mechanism (you can view its documentation with `man inotify`)  Bear in mind that there is no identification of the actor, and when the actor is short lived like this you can't then go do an `lsof` type search to figure out who it was.

Comment: Thank you for reply Chris. I've tried also following `ps -elf | grep -E 'log|date'` to find the process that is writing to file, I suppose this does not work for the same reason (I/O scheduler) as `lsof`. Can you confirm or reject it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file

Use `auditctl -w /path/to/that/file -p wa` to log file writing in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Find some fields like `ppid`.

Finally, we find who is writtng our file.